How to send Discord embed with background image and user avatar/info
I'm fairly new to making discord bots using python, and I'm trying to copy a feature i saw on some bots. one of them is this:

A discord embed with an image background and user avatar in the middle and name below
here is what I made so far
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel ID)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description= f'Welcome **{member.mention}** to the sever',
        color=0xff55ff,
        timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

how do I achieve this embed above?

You will need to use some image manipulation library to perform this image editing and then upload it along with Embed. One of the most used libraries for manipulating images with Python is Pillow. My suggestion is that you create a model image, with the avatar space blank. Then you just need to paste the member's avatar in this space.
